# What is MKTeleportingUserLocation?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I saw this in list of annotations

```
(lldb) po [self.theMapView annotations]
$6 = 0x20a61ff0 <__NSArrayM 0x20a61ff0>
(
<BGAddressAnnotation: 0x236fad50>,
<BGAddressAnnotation: 0x23646a00>,
<BGAddressAnnotation: 0x259f20f0>,
<BGAddressAnnotation: 0x259f7480>,
<BGAddressAnnotation: 0x25811390>,
<BGAddressAnnotation: 0x23646ad0>,
<MKUserLocation: 0x20a868d0>,
<MKTeleportingUserLocation: 0x258f64d0>
)
```

This causes some error because I want to get all annotation that is not MKUserLocation.

I search for MKTeleportingUserLocation at google and couldn't find anything.

Comment: `MKTeleportingUserLocation` results in 81 results on Google. https://www.google.co.in/search?q=MKTeleportingUserLocation&rlz=1C5CHFA_enIN529IN529&aq=f&oq=MKTeleportingUserLocation&aqs=chrome.0.57j60j62.340j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: None of them explains what it is.

Answer (score 2):

This is undocumented stuff, so my guess here is that MKTeleportingUserLocation is the annotation that replaces the old currentLocation annotation when your phone/simulator moves the currentLocation annotation a great distance. Seemingly, it is responsible for shrinking itself and removing itself from the mapView's annotation array.

From https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/MKTeleportingUserLocationView.h

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(id)arg1 finished:(BOOL)arg2;
- (id)dotShrinkAnimation;
- (id)initWithFrame:(struct CGRect { struct CGPoint { float x_1_1_1; float x_1_1_2; } x1;     struct CGSize { float x_2_1_1; float x_2_1_2; } x2; })arg1;
- (void)orderOut;
```

From this I infer that this annotation is responsible for shrinking and removing itself from the mapView. Try changing the coordinates in the simulator and watch the currentLocation shrink to nothing. Once there is a new currentLocation the old one becomes a teleportingUserLocation and shrinks to nothing.

Put this

```
NSLog(@"%@", [self.mapView annotations]);
```

in your

```
locationManager:didUpdateLocations:
```

or

```
mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:
```

run it in the simulator, change the coordinates drastically and this should appear in the log

```
2013-05-01 09:28:10.556 Breadcrumb[20222:c07] (
    "<MKUserLocation: 0x8c40cf0>"
)
2013-05-01 09:28:10.931 Breadcrumb[20222:c07] (
    "<MKUserLocation: 0x8c40cf0>",
    "<MKTeleportingUserLocation: 0x18246480>"
)
2013-05-01 09:28:11.930 Breadcrumb[20222:c07] (
    "<MKUserLocation: 0x8c40cf0>"
)
```

Notice that the MKTeleportingUserLocation is gone in the next update.